# Tracking user's location as per Apple Maps directions in iOS app

Tags: ios, location, monitoring, apple-maps

I am creating an iOS app that has "SoS" functionality and alert based on user's moment/direction. In the app, first the user will set the destination and based on that it will plot the Apple map with directions as in below screenshot.
[image]

When the user starts moving as per the directions, I want to alert the SoS contacts if any deviation is there from the actual route (approx 100 meters range deviation)

 
I am using CLLocationManager to capture location of the user.
How can I keep track of the user as per the directions plotted?